# How to stop a sound when the stop button is clicked in snack expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am making an app which has some buttons that play different sounds, and a stop button which stops all the sounds. However, it works only when the current sound playing stops, and does not play any other music. Is the function incorrect? Here is the code(the other buttons are written in the same way as the first button):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, Alert, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {Audio} from "expo-av";

class Button1 extends React.Component {
   playSound1 = async () => {
     await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
       {uri:"https://s1.yt.ninja/@download/23481-602b351bd79f3-10112020-252-320-file-10112020/mp3/lcVNSPXM2Nc/The%2BUntamed%2BOST%2B%257C%2B%25E9%2599%2588%25E6%2583%2585%25E4%25BB%25A4%2BMain%2BThemed%2BSong%25E3%2580%258A%25E6%2597%25A0%25E7%25BE%2581%2BWu%2BJi%25E3%2580%258B%25E2%2580%2594%25E2%2580%2594Xiao%2BZhan%2B%25E3%2580%2581Wang%2BYi%2BBo%2BDuet.mp3/9f05bbbdbd17b34a35bd40794186a567e755c50ee15ef6c77345bf1eaf7e8124-1"},
       {shouldPlay:true}
     )
  }



 render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{
        backgroundColor : "#D1A5C9",
        marginTop: 30,
        marginLeft: 25,
        width: 280,
        height: 40,
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
      onPress={this.playSound1}>

      <Text style={{
        color:"white",
       fontSize: 30,
      }}>Sound 1</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

class StopButton extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity style={{
        backgroundColor : "black",
        marginTop: 50,
        marginLeft: 40,
        width: 250,
        height: 40,
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
      onPress={() => {
        Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(false)
      }}>

      <Text style={{
        color:"white",
       fontSize: 30,
      }}>Stop Sound</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}



export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button1/>
        <Button2/>
        <Button3/>
        <Button4/>
        <Button5/>
        <StopButton/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work, but only on your phone, not the simulators or the web options

But once you stop it, it wont start sound again ever, unless you add this

```
    class SoundButton6 extends Component {
  render() {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      marginLeft: 100,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'black',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      width: 200,
      height: 100,
      borderRadius: 100,
      marginTop: 10,
    }}
    onPress={ () => {
      Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true);
    }}>
    <Text
      style={{
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 35,
      }}>
      Resume
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
   }
    }
```

a resume button

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by using the instance of the Audio.Sound to stop the audio.

For Ex:

```
const {
    sound: soundObject,
    status,
  } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require('./assets/sounds/hello.mp3'), { shouldPlay: true });
```

and **on the stop button action** process the soundObject to stop the music:

```
onStop = async () => {
    soundObject.stopAsync()
}
```

for more details check out the official docs from expo AV

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#audiosetaudiomodeasyncmode